# SWIG: Passing binary data fails

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, swig, cpython

I'm using a C-Library with `python bindings` generated by `swig`. I want to pass an arbitrary python string to the C-Library. This string contains unprintable characters, e.g:

`\xff\x0A\82`

The C-Library uses an `char` to deal with this data.
For converting I use following swig typemap:

```
%typemap(in) (char *data, int size)
{
        if(!PyUnicode_Check($input))
        {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "String value required");
                return NULL;
        }

        $1 = PyBytes_AsString(PyUnicode_AsUTF8String($input));
        $2 = PyUnicode_GetSize($input);
}
```

This partly works. Only values between **0x00** and **0x7F** work. The value **0xFF** gets converted to a wrong value namely **0xC3**.

Has anyone suggestions to get this work for **0x00** to **0xFF**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unicode string `'\xff'` is converted into the UTF-8 byte sequence `b'\xc3\xbf'` exactly as you have coded.

If you want to send byte data, use a byte string (`b'\xff\x0a\x82'`) and use a `PyBytes` method to convert it to a `char*` and size:

```
%typemap(in) (char* data,int size) (Py_ssize_t len) %{
    if(PyBytes_AsStringAndSize($input,&$1,&len) == -1)
        return NULL;
    $2 = (int)len;
%}
```

Note that this should work on 32- and 64-bit Windows and null bytes can be included in the data, since the size is explicitly extracted and it handles the possibility of 64-bit `Py_ssize_t`.